# Getting the latest item in an observable sequence using RX in C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, synchronous, reactive

take the following as an example:

```
var ob = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).StartWith(500).Replay(1).RefCount();
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to obtain the value of the latest item in the sequence at any given time "synchronously". Which means extensions like `FirstAsync` can't make it up for me.

The `StartWith` and `Replay` bit ensures that there will always be a value, and the `RefCount` bit is necessary in my actual code to detect when I can do some disposal actions.

So to simulate this "any given time" part, let's try getting the latest value after 5 seconds:

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Subscribe(x =>
{
    // Try to get latest value from "ob" here.
});
```

So with a 5 second delay, I need to get the value `5` out of the sequence and these are what I have tried so far with no success:

1. `ob.First()` - returns 500
2. `ob.Latest().Take(1)` - same as above
3. `ob.MostRecent(-1).First()` - same as above
4. `ob.MostRecent(-1)` - gives me an `IEnumerable<long>` full of "500"
5. `ob.Last()` - never returns because it's waiting for the sequence to complete which it never will
6. `ob.Latest().Last()` - same as above
7. `ob.ToTask().Result` - same as above
8. `ob.ToEnumerable()` - same as above
9. `ob.MostRecent().Last()` same as above

It seems there's not much resources around that people can actually do this. The closest I can find is this: "[Rx: operator for getting first and most recent value from an Observable stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693429/)", but it is not a synchronous call after all (still using a subscription) so it doesn't work for me.

Does any body know if this is actually doable?

Comment: I would suggest there is loads of content out there to help you do this. However you may want to read up on what Hot/Cold observable sequences are. This hopefully will guide you to why the RefCount operator isn't behaving as you would expect. `StartWith` and `Replay(1)` could also be swapped with `Publish(500)` giving you `BehaviourSubject<T>` semantics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To point out why your code probably isn't working as you expect it to

```
var ob = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).StartWith(500).Replay(1).RefCount();
//Note at this point `ob` has never been subscribed to,
// so the Reference-count is 0 i.e. has not be connected.

Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Subscribe(x =>
{
    // Try to get latest value from "ob" here.

    //Here we make our first subscription to the `ob` sequence.
    //  This will connect the sequence (invoke subscribe)
    //   which will
    //      1) invoke StartWith
    //      2) invoke onNext(500)
    //      3) invoke First()
    //      4) First() will then unsubscribe() as it has the single value it needs
    //      5) The refCount will now return to 0
    //      6) The sequence will be unsubscribed to.
    ob.First().Dump();  

    //Any future calls like `ob.First()` will thus always get the value 500.
});
```

Potentially what you want is

```
var ob = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Publish(500);
var connection = ob.Connect();
//Note at this point `ob` has never been subscribed to, so the ReferenceCount is 0 i.e. has not be connected.

var subscription = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Subscribe(x =>
{
    // Try to get latest value from "ob" here.
    ob.First().Dump();
});

//Sometime later
subscription.Dispose();
connection.Dispose()
```

HOWEVER, You really don't want to be mixing Synchronous calls with Rx. You also generally don't want to be subscribing within a subscription (as `.First()` is a subscription). What you probably mean to be doing is getting the latest value, and stashing it somewhere. Using `.First()` is just a slippery slope. You probably would be better writing something like

```
var subscription = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .SelectMany(_=>ob.Take(1))
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        //Do something with X here.
        x.Dump();
    });
```

Comment: "Note at this point `ob` has never been subscribed to, so the Reference-count is 0 i.e. has not be connected." <<< This is exactly what I was missing. I was trying to query a hot observable that has never been connected and subscribed to so the sequence never started. Thank you Lee! I didn't have to subscribe within a subscription. The `Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))` part is just for the sake of simulating querying the value at a later time. In my real case, this query is triggered by some other events which don't involve subscribing to an observable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
var ob = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).StartWith(500);

var latestAndThenTheRest =
    Observable
        .Create<long>(o =>
        {
            var bs = new BehaviorSubject<long>(1);
            var s1 = ob.Subscribe(bs);
            var s2 = bs.Subscribe(o);
            return new CompositeDisposable(s1, s2);
        });
```

The only thing that you need to consider here is that `ob` must be a hot observable for this to even make sense. If it were cold then every subscriber would get a brand new subscription to the start of the `ob` sequence.

Comment: Hmm, I think you have made a rare error here? This is just a pipeline of `ob` through a `BehaviorSubject`. `ob.Publish(1)`? or even better bullet the magic `1` value and move the magic `500` to the publish method? Is there some missing code? Or have I missed something.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - Yes, I think you're right. I was trying to show how to use `BehaviourSubject` as per KeyboardDrummer's answer/comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify this a bit, and thanks for @LeeCampbell's answer.

What was not working:

```
var ob = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).StartWith(500).Replay(1).RefCount();
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Subscribe(x =>
{
    ob.First().Dump();
    // This gives you 500.
    // Because this is the first time any one subscribes to the observable,
    // so it starts right here and gives you the initial value.
});
```

What would actually work:

```
var ob = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).StartWith(500).Replay(1).RefCount();
ob.Subscribe(); // Subscribe to start the above hot observable immediately.
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Subscribe(x =>
{
    ob.First().Dump(); 
    // This would give you either 3 or 4, depending on the speed and timing of your computer.
});
```

Comment: Note that this obviously has a leak as you throw away the subscription token. Thus you can never dispose of the subscription, thus the refCount will never go to zero, thus the `Observable.Interval` will run until the process is killed. A better option is to just replace the usage of the `RefCount` with manually calling `Connect()`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this answer helps you, but have you looked into BehaviorSubject? It's an IObservable that remembers its latest value. It's a bit like a combination of a regular variable and an observable in one.

Otherwise, why don't you subscribe to 'ob' and store the latest value in a variable yourself?

Comment: Storing the latest value in a variable myself is an option but my understanding of `Replay(1)` is that the latest value is cached by RX internally so that I don't have to cache it myself anymore. I'll look into `BehaviorSubject`.